# Elastically Object movement in unity3d

Tags: unity, c#, movement

I want to move an object towards the destination elastically. Currently I am using Vector3.Lerp it working to move the object, start with high speed and reached at destination with low speed but missing elastic effects.

```
float i = 50, t = 0;
        while (t < 1)
        {
            t += Time.deltaTime / i;
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, newPostionAtDistance, t);
            transform.LookAt(targetFollow.transform);
            if (transform.position.ToString() == newPostionAtDistance.ToString())
            {
                //StartCoroutine(CamElasticMoveBackEffetcts());
                Debug.LogWarning("Object reached to the point.");
                yield break;
            }

            smoothTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return 0;
            i++;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean elastically? Like there is a spring attached or what?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested it but it seems you may want to use the `Berp` method from [here](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Mathfx#C.23_-_Mathfx.cs), instead of Lerp.

```
public static float Berp(float start, float end, float value)
{
    value = Mathf.Clamp01(value);
    value = (Mathf.Sin(value * Mathf.PI * (0.2f + 2.5f * value * value * value)) * Mathf.Pow(1f - value, 2.2f) + value) * (1f + (1.2f * (1f - value)));
    return start + (end - start) * value;
}
```

You can modify the values to increase/decrease the 'shakiness'. The default ease function looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If by elastic, you mean as though it was attached by a rubber band:

Whenever it passes the object, increase the force applied to it (with a maximum force of the remaining distance). To determine if it passes the object, you can check if the distance from the object increased since the previous frame. But be careful of performance issues.

As a side note, I'd be interested to hear more efficient alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for input i have update my question with picture hope it will help you to understand!